# iOS Local Notification - Action on Click

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

So I have managed to set up local notification in my app by doing so.

```
NSDate *notifTime = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:time];
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
UILocalNotification *notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

if (notif) {
    notif.fireDate = notifTime;
    notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    notif.repeatInterval = 0;
    notif.alertTitle = title;
    notif.alertBody = text;

    if (sound == nil) {

        NSLog(@"default sound");
    }

    else {

        NSLog(@"other sound");
        notif.soundName = sound;
    };


    [app scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
}
```

inside of a method that is called

```
- (void)createDateNotification:(NSString*) title alertText: (NSString*)text timeToWait: (NSTimeInterval)time soundToPlay: (NSString*)sound;
```

and when I call that method, The notification runs just like expected. My problem is that in my game I want it to be when the user clickes on the local notification that it will run a method which now just does so

```
-(void)rewardUser {

NSLog(@"User rewarded")

}
```

but sometimes it may run a different method and I don't know how do do it. Anything from swift to objective c will be appreciated. Much thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by doing this. When creating the alert, I set the action to a public string in my class which is called `action` and as @songchenwen mentioned, I overrided the didReceiveLocalNotification to check if the `action` is equal to a number of variables and if so run a method for each one.

I called the mothod like this setting a string for the action

```
 [self createReminderNotification:@"Give50Coins" messageTitle:@"t" messageBody:@"gfdhgsh" timeToWait:2 soundToPlay:@"audio.wav"];
```

And in the method I initialised the notification setting all the details.

```
NSDate *notifTime = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:time];
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
UILocalNotification *notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

action = actionAfterNotifiy;

if (notif) {

    notif.fireDate = notifTime;
    notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    notif.repeatInterval = 0;
    notif.alertTitle = title;
    notif.alertBody = message;

    if (sound == nil) {

        NSLog(@"default sound");
    }

    else {

        NSLog(@"other sound");
    };

}

[app scheduleLocalNotification: notif];
```

and in the `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification*)notification`

I did this,

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

if ([action isEqualToString:@"Give50Coins"]) {

    NSLog(@"wheyy");
}
 else {
  //random stuff here
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Override `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification*)notification` in your `AppDelegate` and do your thing.

Comment: What if there is multiple actions? I'll try work around with it thanks!

Comment: Managed to get it to work, I'll respond with what I did

Comment: In your UILocalNotification set the alertAction values, then in the receive method , you can get the alertAction value in the UILocalNotification instance.